# Oozie and Hue: Permission Denied while running shell script

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie, hue

I have a shell script `sample_shell.sh` in HDFS `/user/user`which looks like the below:

```
 source /user/user/params_new.cfg
 echo "HELLO WORLD"
 echo $layer
```

The params_new.cfg is also in HDFS `/user/user` directory whose contents are:

```
layer="S"
```

I'm new to Oozie and trying to set up an Oozie work flow in Hue which will execute the sample_shell.sh script. The properties are as below:

```
<workflow-app name="shell_sample" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
<start to="shell_sample"/>
<action name="shell_sample">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <exec>/user/user/sample_shell.sh</exec>
        <file>/user/user/sample_shell.sh#sample_shell.sh</file>
        <file>/user/user/params_new.cfg#params_new.cfg</file>
          <capture-output/>
    </shell>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
</action>
<kill name="kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```

But I get the following error:

```
Log Length: 165
./sample_shell.sh: line 2: /user/user/params_new.cfg: Permission denied
 Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class     [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
```

I don't understand what's going wrong! If I remove the `source /user/user/params_new.cfg` and `echo $layer` line from the sample_shell.sh code, it works fine!

The permissions are as follows.

```
 -rwxrwxrwx   3 user_name supergroup       1590 2015-03-19 04:01 /user/user/params_new.cfg
 -rwxrwxrwx   3 user_name supergroup        139 2015-03-19 04:18 /user/user/sample_shell.sh
```

Comment: Which version of Hue are you using?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Check permissions for both /user and /user/user directories

Comment: I guess you should give the OP a hint how to do that since he understand not get this obvious message.

Comment: @dan the permission for the /user directory is as follows:
drwxrwxrwt   - user_name  supergroup          0 2015-03-10 04:37 /user
So what is the problem?

Comment: @user1452759 there are four things that require permission. Your files, the directory that holds your files, the directory that holds that directory. Since I saw your files had 777 permissions, I wanted you to check both the directory /user and the directory /user/user, it looks like you have only checked /user.

Comment: @dan Both the directories /user and /user/user directories have the appropriate permissions. The problem was in the way I call the params_new.cfg file in my code and access the variables inside it. I just needed to give "source params_new.cfg" and not the entire path to params_new.cfg.